# Add column to existing MySQL tables containing table name + increment

Tags: mysql

I have a MySQL database with given content. I need to create a new column for each table, called 'muid' (migration unique id), and I need to fill each row with unique id in the following format: table_name_ + row_number.

So, the rows for the user table will be "user_0", "user_1", "user_2".

I am currently doing this with PHP - but that takes lots and lots of time. Can this be done with MySQL at all?

Comment: Why do you need table names in ID? You could add new `id` column, make it primary and auto_increment; the values will be 1, 2, 3, 4, 5....

Comment: It's a long story - but to cut it short, I receive a ready database to migrate into Drupal. And Drupal's Migrate module does not handle items that don't have unique id's well. So, I am looking at a way to add unique id's myself, to the given table.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suspect there are a number of ways to solve this.  My approach would be to do something like this:

```
alter table mydb.mytable add column muid varchar(15);


set @i = 0;
update mydb.mytable set muid = concat('mytable_', (@i:=@i+1));
```

In my test, this results in the muid column having values like mytable_1, mytable_2, etc.

Comment: An unexpected solution without a cursor! Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Use following to create new column

```
DECLARE @Table AS VARCHAR(200)
SET @Table ='Test'
EXEC ('ALTER TABLE ' + @Table + ' ADD muid VARCHAR(50)')
```

After that, update each record using a cursor

[How to use cursor to update record](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8652653/how-to-use-cursor-to-update-record)